# Which provider should I select to connect to Excel version 11 through AdoConnection?

Tags: excel, connection-string, ado

I need to connect to Excel table through `TADOConnection`, and I don't know what to write into the `ConnectionString` property. For Excel Version 8 I use Jet, for 12 I use ACE, what about 11?

And how should the ConnectionString look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything prior to v12 can use the Jet connection string.  [This site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel) is at the top of my bookmark list, because I am always forgetting the proper ConnectionString syntax.

**EDIT:**
I've never run into an ISAM-related error before, but [this discussion thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/62ee4978-ca29-48d3-9367-6dd4ab639d2d/) has good info on getting the connection strings exactly correct.

Comment: When I use Jet with this excel file I get error "Could not find installable ISAM". Do you know how to solve it?